# MVVM/Room pulling a single item from the Dao or Repository, what is the best approach?

Tags: android, android-room, android-mvvm

I want to get a single item using MVVM/Room and edit it in a detail screen. I followed a number of guides and examples for creating a MVVM/Room application. And in many of them the Repository class looks like this:

```
public class ScenarioRepository {

    private static final String TAG="ScenarioRepository";

    private ScenarioDao scenarioDao;
    private LiveData<List<Scenario>> allScenarios;


    public ScenarioRepository(Application application) {

        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
        scenarioDao = database.scenarioDao();
        allScenarios = scenarioDao.getAllScenarios();
    }
    ....
}
```

The examples focus on filling a RecyclerView and when editing one of the records pass all values from the RecyclerView to the edit screen. Frequently there is more information in the record than appears on the RecyclerView, so I would prefer to pull the record from the database and have seen some MVVM implementations where the DAO has a specific call for an item like this:

```
@Query("select * from Scenario where id = :id")
Scenario getItembyId(int id);
```

What is the best way to retrieve the Scenario I want in this example? Why do I need to get an individual item when the full list of Scenarios is pulled by the Repository from the DOW in the constructor? Should I have a way in the repository to pull the Scenario from member variable allScenarios in the Repository as opposed to going back to the database/Room?

**UPDATE**
I followed [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing) which covered the master/detail scenario very well. The I extended the RecyclerView like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reSPN7mgshI&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDihTpkRs6SpZhqgBqPU118&index=6) which made it easy to set the item during the onItemClick event and pass it to the ViewModel so the detail fragment could get it.

Comment: You could use `Transformations.map()` to create a `LiveData<Scenario>` that filters based on your desired ID, wrapping the `allScenarios` `LiveData`. Then, when Room emits a new `List<Scenario>` through `allScenarios`, your `Transformations.map()` `LiveData` will also emit a `Scenario` pulled from that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query for filtering by id is useful in the case that you do not need an entire list of data but just single items.

If you observe the entire list anyways, but for certain UI components need to get an item by id, I would suggest you to filter the list for that specific item id.

You could retrieve your object by a query like in your question, or if you want to observe for changes in the database, wrap it in a LiveData.

Comment: Essentially I have two fragments, the RecyclerView and the detail. This piece of code was focused on the RecyclerView. I could change the repository so the complete list is not pulled in the constructor and create a 2nd member variable LiveData<Scenario> which pulls a single item from the DAO. Is that what you're recommending?

Comment: Every example I see pulls the full list in the constructor of the repository. Some show the query in the Dao for a single item, but I never see it implemented in the repository.

Comment: I would recommend you to share the same viewmodel instance between those two fragments if the same activity hosts them, then just observe the list and if a single item changes, then the list  anyway gets updated too, so you could simply observe the list and filter it for the itemId that you need.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Any guidance on where I should look to get a specific Scenario from the LiveData<List<Scenario>> given a id? I am new to android programming and could use an expert opinion to shorten the learning cycle.

Comment: In case that you have something like a recylcerview on item click (fragment 1) -> item detail view (fragment 2),
the first fragment would observe the LiveData and pass the items to the recyclerview adapter, in the second fragment you would also observe the list, but filter it for the specific ID and get the item from the list with that specific id and display it.

Comment: I actually extended the adapter so on the onItemClick event I get the whole scenario. Just need to figure out how to pass it from fragment to fragment.